# Calculate percentage changes in a data frame for subgroups over various periods of time

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, percentage

There have been some similar questions however I haven't come across one that helps with my particular case; Every quarter a count of events get recorded for each event name, there are several passes done for each event to catch missing counts. I want to compare the percentage change of counts in each pass with their previous number of counts in their respective pass.

This is the data I currently have (different values but same format):

```
ID <- c(221, 221, 345, 345, 209, 209, 209, 19, 19, 19, 536, 536, 536)
Pass <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
Event_count <- c(2000, 100, 2050, 150, 50000, 10000, 600, 51000, 11000, 700, 50500, 10500, 650)
Event_name <- c(rep('filter', 4) , rep('observations', 9))
Date <- c(rep('2015-03-01',2) , rep('2015-06-01',2) , rep('2015-03-01',3) , rep('2015-06-01',3), rep('2015-09-01',3))  
df <- data.frame(ID, Pass, Event_count, Event_name, Date)

    ID Pass Event_count   Event_name       Date
1  221    1        2000       filter 2015-03-01
2  221    2         100       filter 2015-03-01
3  345    1        2050       filter 2015-06-01
4  345    2         150       filter 2015-06-01
5  209    1       50000 observations 2015-03-01
6  209    2       10000 observations 2015-03-01
7  209    3         600 observations 2015-03-01
8   19    1       51000 observations 2015-06-01
9   19    2       11000 observations 2015-06-01
10  19    3         700 observations 2015-06-01
11 536    1       50500 observations 2015-09-01
12 536    2       10500 observations 2015-09-01
13 536    3         650 observations 2015-09-01
```

And this is the output I want (If you can think of a better way to display this data please let me know!)

```
Percentage_change <- c(NA, NA, 2.5, 50, NA, NA, NA, 2, 10, 16.67, -0.98, -4.55, -7.14)
df2 <- data.frame(ID, Pass, Event_count, Event_name, Date,Percentage_change)

    ID Pass Event_count   Event_name       Date Percentage_change
1  221    1        2000       filter 2015-03-01                NA
2  221    2         100       filter 2015-03-01                NA
3  345    1        2050       filter 2015-06-01              2.50
4  345    2         150       filter 2015-06-01             50.00
5  209    1       50000 observations 2015-03-01                NA
6  209    2       10000 observations 2015-03-01                NA
7  209    3         600 observations 2015-03-01                NA
8   19    1       51000 observations 2015-06-01              2.00
9   19    2       11000 observations 2015-06-01             10.00
10  19    3         700 observations 2015-06-01             16.67
11 536    1       50500 observations 2015-09-01             -0.98
12 536    2       10500 observations 2015-09-01             -4.55
13 536    3         650 observations 2015-09-01             -7.14
```

I've only got relatively basic knowledge of R so I don't know if there are any packages that can help me with this - any help / explanations that you can provide me with will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to return the values you want

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Event_name, Pass) %>% 
  mutate(Percentage_change=(Event_count/lag(Event_count)-1)*100)
```

Comment: Such a concise solution, thanks! This method will also make getting the change in absolute counts super easy which is what I'll be doing next.